# Why doesn't the Bible have verses or passages that hint to God's Infiniteness?

Tags: attributes-of-god

Christian Scholars usually allude to God an Infiniteness, i.e: space (not matter) is infinite, and God fills the whole space. Also, God is Eternal (infinity in time). Look for example, **Thomas Aquinas,** on **(Infinity of God),** on **encyclopedia.com.**

I searched much more in the Bible to find Verses or passages that hint to Infiniteness of God, especially in Space and Consciousness, I couldn't find.

To be accurate, there are two passages that hint to God's Omnipresence, **i.e: Psalms 139:7-12, and Hebrews 4:13.**

**Omnipresent doesn't mean Infinite in Space and Consciousness.**

Finite in Space and Consciousness doesn't mean lack of Omnipotence and Presence of Evil. I.e: doesn't justify the Presence of Evil.

Of course God is Infinite in Time, i.e: He is Eternal. I.e: He **can't,** and **couldn't** die.

In philosophy there are many philosophers who assume God's Finiteness, e.g: **Charles Renouvier** and **William James.**

Could you, please, give me Biblical evidences for God **(Finiteness)** or **(Infiniteness)** in **Space,** and **Consciousness?**

Comment: Psalm 139:7–13; Isaiah 66:1; Jeremiah 23:23–24; Acts 17:27–28.  To meet the guidelines of this list you need to ask about a passage, not a topic without giving a passage.

Comment: • God is creator.  Gen 1:1, Ps 33:6, 9, Isa 44:24, 45:18, John 1:1-3, Col 1:16.
• God is the sustainer of all creation.  Col 1:17, Heb 1:3.
• God is (obviously) omnipotent.  Dan 4:17, 25, 35, Matt 19:26, Rev 19:6.
• God is omniscient.  Job 37:16, Ps 139:1-18, 147:5, 1 John 3:20, Isa 46:9-11, Jer 1:5.
• God is omnipresent.  Ps 139:7-12, Heb 4:13.
• God is the source of all life.  John 1:4, 5:26.
• God is eternal and immortal.  Ps 90:2, Rev 1:8, 1 Tim 6:15, 16.

Comment: I agree with Perry Webb that this question does not fit with the rules on this site but we have provided some help anyway.

Comment: @dottard the question is about biblical theology. I need Verses or passages. The question is completely fitting.

Comment: Question looking for a text a explicitly against the rules.  Your question "give me verses" confirms this.  In any case, we have provided a good list of such verses in the comments above.

Comment: @dottard excuse me, I will edit the question.

Comment: This question still does not provide a specific Bible Passage to analyse.

Comment: @dottard I introduced some passages to analyse.

Comment: "Christian Scholars usually allude to God an Infiniteness". I think we need at least a specific quote (in order to see what the scholars actually said). "space is infinite" actually this statement is false from physics perspective. Matter is finite, distance in and between matter defines space, therefore space is finite. God is outside matter / space, because He created it (and also in all matter again because He created and sustains it). You could say that God is infinite because He is not limited by space / matter.

Comment: If we say that God is infinite, from human perspective (all the Bible was written by the men that were inspired by God and for the men), His infinity is manifested by His Omnipresence.

Comment: @leonard Omnipresence of God doesn't mean His Infiniteness, this is speculative. Omnipresence of God, just means that He pervades all His creation, i.e: the universe and the living beings.

Comment: @salah Yes, I know that "omnipresence" does not mean "infiniteness", I've never stated that. I said that FROM HUMAN PERSPECTIVE, His infinity is manifested by His Omnipresence. Which is a totally different thing. Sorry by the misunderstanding. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Could you give me Verses of the Bible that hint to God Infiniteness?**

**GOD HAS ETERNAL EXISTENCE.**

In mathematics we deal with the concept of positive and negative numbers, we count infinitely either way. We can also apply this to the span of life of the creator. Psalm 90:2  [noted below] teaches that God exists "from everlasting to everlasting". God has no beginning and will have no end.

Psalm 90:2 NASB

> 2 Before the mountains were born  [a]Or You gave birth to the earth
> and the world,  Even from everlasting to everlasting, You are God.

Psalm 93:2 NASB

> Your throne is established from of old;  You are from eternity.

Isaiah 40:28 NASB

> 28 Do you not know? Have you not heard?  The Everlasting God, the
> Lord, the Creator of the ends of the earth. Does not become weary or
> tired. His understanding is unsearchable.

1 Timothy 1:17 NASB

> Now to the King [a]eternal, immortal, invisible, the only God, be
> honor and glory [b]forever and ever. Amen.

Revelation 15:3 NASB

> 3 And they *sang the song of Moses, the bond-servant of God, and the
> song of the Lamb, saying, “Great and marvelous are Your works, Lord
> God, the Almighty;  Righteous and true are Your ways, King of the
> [a]nations!